# Where should video be hosted to stream for an iphone app

Tags: iphone, video

Looking for a way to not have a publicly hosted video be used in an iphone application. Youttube or Vimeo seem like the obvious choices for free hosting of video, but the public nature is discouraging. Want to charge for video content, so making it free to all defeats the purpose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely require a **CDN, Content Distribution/Delivery Network** and then write a front-end application that authorizes access to that content.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network

Level3, AT&T all have some kind of offering. Some more dynamic than others.

**Good Luck**

Comment: Will probably go with the CDN, most likely through Amazon. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some sort of paid hosting with enough bandwidth and storage would be the natural choice.

Comment: For the development, maybe. If the application will become an instant hit, it can not be scaled quickly. And many apps/websites get only a few bursts (recent, Slashdot/Digg post, etc.) of interest that can make the apps "take hold".